# Rails not minifying

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a project that does not minify CSS or JS in production.

Unfortunately I've never had this problem, and I'm just not very familiar with how the asset pipeline works in detail to debug the issue.

My question is, what are the main points/settings that I need to check to make sure that is enabled?

It is properly combining the different files into a single JS and CSS file... it's just not minifying.

So far I've added `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` to `production.rb`, and `uglifier` to the `Gemfile`, but still no dice.

I'm using a Rails `3.2.12` upgraded from Rails `2`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**This answer applies for rails 4**

One of the reasons when rails-4 won't minify assets is when the RAILS_ENV is not set to production.

This usually happens when you pre-compile assets and run webrick in prod mode using:
`rails s -e 'production'` 
but still the resulting application.css and application.js are concatenated but **not** minified.

To solve this, use the following to specify the env while precompiling assets:

> $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Also if you are upgrading from rails 3 to rails 4, please note that `config.assets.compress = true` directive in production.rb is not longer effective for rails 4. You'll need to add the following directives in your `config/environments/production.rb` file for it to minify js and css files:

```
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier # make sure the 'uglifier' gem is included before adding this line
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass # if you are using the sass-rails gem, this line is unnecessary
```

Comment: Note that if you use `sass-rails`, no need to specify `config.assets.css_compressor`, as documentation states (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark)

Comment: Also note that running assets:precompile a second time won't do anything unless the original files have changed. You won't see changes in production until you bounce your server.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it's not minifying? Did you run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

or do you use capistrano for deployment? If you use capistrano for deployment make sure to add this line on top of deploy.rb

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Otherwise please post the steps you're taking on getting it to work